# Can't have the Leaflet panTo option 'duration' doing its job

Tags: leaflet, duration, pan

The following instruction won't work as I expect:

```
map.panTo(e.latlng, {animate: true, duration: 1.0});
```

I've tried different values : 0.5, 1.0, 10.0, 1000.0, 1, 10
but the panning is just as fast!

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello, please explain more what is the expected behaviour of that code, thanks.

Comment: Hi, "e" is the result of a click event on the map. map.panTo(...) centers the map on the clicked point with a motion effect. This motion rendering is too fast for me, I'd like it to be less brutal. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you're using the latest Leaflet version? I just tried this code in 0.6.4 and it worked perfectly, panning slowly as expected:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
  map.panTo(e.latlng, {animate: true, duration: 5.0});
});
```

Comment: could this also be used to animate `fitBounds` all the way from a zoomlevel 10 to 15?